# Android - how to file a bug?

Tags: android, bug-tracking

I asked a question a few days ago and no one seems to know the answer. 
I asked this question about camera not coming back to onactivityresult
[camera request no activityresult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758803/camera-request-no-activityresult)
I'd like to file a bug if no one knows how to solve a problem. Where can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Google shows, that [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) is bug tracker for android.